# #map_find in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, enumerable

Return the first keyword matched in a set of text lines.

I found `#map` and `#find` and `#find` again solve the problem. A convoluted solution that doesn't satisfy.

```rb
["unrelated", "start something", "stop something"].map do |t|
  ["start","stop"].find {|k| k == t.split(/[ \t]{1,}/).first}
end.find {|k| !k.nil?}
```

The above returns `"start"` as expected.  A convenience method as `#map_find` may compact it. Or maybe a clever selection algorithm for this problem exists already. Please advise.

---

### Edit

Another solution:

```rb
keys = ["start", "stop"]
reg = Regexp.new("^"+keys.first+" |^"+keys.last+" ")
["unrelated", "start something", "stop something"].map{|m| m.slice(reg)}.find {|k| !k.nil?}
```

Comment: It is a bit unclear from your example which order is more important – the one in the lines or the keywords. If the keywords were `%w[stop start]` or the lines were `['stop something', 'start something']` would you then still expect `start` to be returned or would you expect `stop` in such cases?

Comment: In your example I would expect `stop`.  The first line with matching keyword defines the keyword returned.

Comment: This would also work: `keyword = arr.find { |a| a[/\A(start|stop)\b/] } && Regexp.last_match[0]` (Or shorter: `arr.find { |a| a[/\A(start|stop)\b/] } && $1`)

Comment: Your implementation is still 4x faster than mine.  Would have saved 2 tenths of a second by now :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
lines = ["unrelated", "start something", "stop something"]
keywords = /\A(start|stop)/

lines.lazy.map { |line| line[keywords] }.find(&:itself)
#=> "start"
```

You might want to skip the `lazy` when the number of `lines` is small. The bigger it is the more you will benefit from `lazy`.

Comment: I need to return the matching keyword, not the line.

Comment: For some reason your original solution is 11x faster than either of mine.

Comment: Because of `lazy` – which adds a bit of initial overhead – me version will `map` until a matching line is found and then return immediately. Your version will first evaluate all lines before checking the condition – even if a match was already on the second element (like in your example).

Comment: `lazy` adds a consistent penalty and speed is basically equal to mine. Without your latest is 4x faster.

Comment: As I already wrote in my answer. Only use `lazy` if the number of lines is huge. If the number is small it is not worth it.

Comment: It's never more than 10 lines so I will skip it.  Thanks for the useful answer.